# what is the exact 6 digit color code for "set1" palette in Seanborn

Tags: plot, colors, seaborn

It was a red and blue,but not the same as the color if you just use customized color by
palette="red" or palette="blue"

Comment: `pal = sns.color_palette('Set1', 6); print(pal.as_hex())` gives `['#e41a1c', '#377eb8', '#4daf4a', '#984ea3', '#ff7f00', '#ffff33']`

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for! Thanks!